# the limit is true $ \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} z\sin(\frac{1}{z})=0 $

Tags: complex-analysis

I am checking whether the  limit  is true or not. $z$ is complex number
\begin{equation} 
\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} z\sin(\frac{1}{z})=0
\end{equation}
I found Laurent series of $z\sin(\frac{1}{z})$ which is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{z})^{2n}\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}(-1)^n$

the series is not defined $z =0$.

Can the Laurent series gives us any information about the limit whether it is true or not ? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list does not exist, since $\displaystyle z\sin\frac1z$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$. That is, there an infinite number of non-zero negative powers in the Laurent series around $z=0$.

Answer (score 5):

Casorati-Weierstrass theorem implies that the limit does not exist. In fact, approaching from $i\mathbb{R}$ gives
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} ih \sin \frac{1}{ih} = -\lim_{h \to 0} h \sinh \frac{1}{h} = -\infty
$$
By l'Hopital.

Answer (score 4):

It might be more intuitive to do the substitution $z=1/w$ to get
$$
\lim_{|w|\to\infty}\frac{\sin w}{w}
$$
which clearly goes to $0$ along the real axis. But along the imaginary axis, the sine function grows exponentially, which outweighs the division by $w$ to give an infinite limit. Therefore the limit is not defined.