# Does $\lim_{z\to 0}\;z\times \sin(\frac{1}{z})$ exist for $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

So I stumbled across the question where i was asked whether $\lim_{z \to 0}\;z\times \sin(\frac{1}{z})$ exists  for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ . I know that if $z \in \mathbb{R}$  ,then the limit exists , but i can't really figure out if the limit will exists $\forall z \in \mathbb{C} $. There were two techniques in my mind for figuring this out that write $z=x+iy$ and check  $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\;(x+iy)\times \sin(\frac{1}{x+iy})$ along different paths and basically try to establish that the limit doesn't exist(Note- I still don't know if limit exists , but i was making an attempt  disproving that the limit exists ) .But i found this time consuming and non elegant .Then i tried expressing $\sin(\frac{1}{z})=\frac{e^{\frac{i}{z}}-e^{\frac{-i}{z}}}{2}$ and $z=|z| \times e^{i\mathrm{Arg}(z)}$ but that too didn't work. Can someone prove or disprove whether the limit exists in an elegant way ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4149086/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1730445/42969

Comment: Hint: if $w=ix,$ then $\sin w =\sinh x.$